# Find by equivalent key in unordered_set of shared_ptr’s

Tags: c++, c++20, unordered-set

In C++20 associative hash containers received new `find` methods that can accept equivalent key types on input. For example, in `std::unordered_set`

```
template< class K > iterator find( const K& x ); //(3)  (since C++20)
```

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set/find

In this example, I try to search in the container of shared_ptrs using raw painter:

```
#include <unordered_set>
#include <memory>

using sptr = std::shared_ptr<int>;

struct ptr_equal
{
    using is_transparent = void;
    bool operator()(const sptr& l, const sptr& r) const { return l == r; }
    bool operator()(const sptr& l, const int* r) const { return l.get() == r; }
    bool operator()(const int* l, const sptr& r) const { return l == r.get(); }
};

struct ptr_hash : public std::hash<const int*>
{
    using is_transparent = void;
    std::size_t operator()(const sptr& s) const
       { return std::hash<const int*>::operator()(s.get()); }
    std::size_t operator()(const int* s) const
       { return std::hash<const int*>::operator()(s); }
};

int main()
{
    auto v = std::make_shared<int>(0);
    std::unordered_set<sptr, ptr_hash, ptr_equal> set{v};
    set.find( v.get() ); //still clang error here
}
```

It works in gcc 11, but not in clang 12: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/P9E5TTba4

```
source>:27:9: error: no matching member function for call to 'find'
```

Is there something wrong with the program or clang does not support new find methods yet?

Comment: Likely just that it is not yet implemented in clang yet. I don't believe any compiler is fully C++20 compliant yet. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support

Comment: Changing your Compiler Explorer example to "clang (trunk)" compiles successfully, so that seems to be your answer.

Comment: If you use the trunk version of clang, it would actually compile.

Comment: Note : I'd be suspicious of `struct ptr_hash : public std::hash<const int*>`. If you want to use inheritance for this `private` inheritance should do the job. Public inheritance exposes you to risks like object slicing. `std::hash` is not polymorphic and was not designed to be inherited from, so you have to be very careful when publicly inheriting it while there is no risk involved in private inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

The above program is correct in C++20. It is a limitation of clang 12 that fails to compile it.

But I was suggested a much more simple technique to solve the original problem (searching in the container having `std::shared_ptr` key by raw pointer without any heap allocations/deallocations), which works starting from C++11:

```
#include <unordered_set>
#include <memory>

using sptr = std::shared_ptr<int>;

int main()
{
    auto v = std::make_shared<int>(0);
    std::unordered_set<sptr> set{v};
    set.find( sptr{ std::shared_ptr<void>(), v.get() } );
}
```